# Does changing f(mystruct *a) to f(const mystruct *a) breaks API/ABI in C?

Tags: c, api, constants, compatibility, abi

```
1: void f(mystruct *a)
2: void f(const mystruct *a)
```

Does changing the function signature from 1->2 break API/ABI in C?
How about changing 2->1?

Answer (score 5):

From C99 standard 6.2.5/26 "Types":

> pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements.

So the ABI/API should not be affected going from 1 to 2. (The API doesn't change because a pointer to a non-const-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to a const-qualified version of the type  - 6.3.2.3/2 "Conversions - Pointers").

However, if you go from 2 to 1, then the API changes because a pointer to a const object cannot be implicitly converted to a pointer to a non-const object. The following code would compile under version 2, but would not compile under version 1:

```
static const mystruct foo;

f(&foo);
```

Answer (score 4):

Other than stated in the two previous answers going from 1->2 may or may not break the API. This depends on the base type `mystruct`. The API would break if other than what the name indicates `mystruct` would be a `typedef` to an array type.

```
typedef struct toto mystruct[1];
```

For such a beast

```
mystruct A;
f(&A);
```

the call to `f` would be valid before the API change but invalid afterwards.

Comment: +1: This is interesting.  It's somewhat similar to the old a-`char **`-is-not-a-`const char **` rule, but it doesn't quite seem similar enough.  What is going on here?

Comment: @Oli, this is because `const` (or any other qualifier) on an array type actually applies to the base type of the array and not the array type itself. So in a sense a `const` qualified variant of an array type doesn't exist. For `typedef double arr[1]` the type of `arr const` is equivalent to `double const[1]`.

Comment: Yes, I guess it makes sense that you can't truly have a `const` array!  But what scenario is the compiler protecting against here?  I can't see an equivalent to http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html for pointer-to-array.

Comment: @Oli, I think this is protecting against nothing, this is just an artifact (defect?) of the language. If you are interested, I just wrote something up a week or so concerning this: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/const-and-arrays/

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by API.  At compile-time, a `T *` may always be implicitly converted to a `const T *` (*Note: apart from the exception that Jens Gustedt has pointed out in his answer!*).  The inverse is not true; a `const T *` won't be implicitly converted to a `T *`, so a cast is always required in order to avoid a compiler error.  So if you change the declaration of an interface function from `const` to non-`const`, then none of your client code will compile.  (You can get round this simply by casting away the `const`-ness in all calls, but doing so should be avoided unless absolutely unavoidable, as the behaviour is undefined, and it means that you've broken your own interface's contract).

At the bit level (i.e. the ABI), there will be no difference between the representations of your pointers or objects.  However, that's not to say that the compiler won't have made optimisation/assumptions based on something being marked `const` when generated machine code the handles these representations; if you cast away the `const`-ness, these assumptions may no longer hold, and the code will break.

Comment: I guess it makes sense that "it may be implicitly converted to `const T *`" although it seems a bit restricting cause it does make sense to operated on the pointer's address itself, i.e. in pseudo `&(* p)`

Comment: @Dima, @Michael Burr: no there are situations where `T*` may not be converted to `T const*`. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the ABI is concerned, no, the `const` only influences errors during compilation stage. Compiled object files should have no remnants of const specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
OLD: void f(mystruct *a)
NEW: void f(const mystruct *a)
```

**ABI:** If `a` was an **out**-parameter, then old apps may be broken.

**API:** Seems to be compatible.

```
OLD: void f(const mystruct *a)
NEW: void f(mystruct *a)
```

**ABI:** The function `f` may try to change a parameter value, that supposed to be unchanged by old apps.

**API:** Compiler error.

**EDIT (1):** This is an example to show a compiler error than changing the parameter to be non-const:

library header.h:

```
struct mystruct {
    int f;
};
void f(struct mystruct *a);
```

application:

```
int main()
{
    const struct mystruct x = {1};
    f(&x);
    return 0;
}
```

compiler error (`gcc -Werror app.c`):

```
error: passing argument 1 of ‘f’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
note: expected ‘struct mystruct *’ but argument is of type ‘const struct mystruct *’
```

It's really a warning in C by default, but an error in C++. So, you will break C-based apps compiled with `-Werror` option and C++-based apps compiled using G++.

Comment: what is compiler error and why? compiles fine here both old and new in either.